# Cordova FileTransfer: upload fails over HTTPS

Tags: ios, cordova, ssl, cordova-plugins

I have an Ionic/Cordova app in production, and it's been working fine until I realized file uploads fail over HTTPS. Everything works perfectly fine when I'm targetting my local dev machine, over HTTP. But when I target our production server over HTTPS, file uploads fail, and then the app freezes.

This is the kind of error I'm getting in XCode's Debug Console:

> 2018-12-10 02:33:43.321578+0330 OnRecord[6189:2478184] [BoringSSL]
>   boringssl_session_errorlog(236) [C3.1:2][0x10b612e80]
>   [boringssl_session_write] SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL(5): operation failed
>   externally to the library

It says the operation failed externally to the library, and I'm confused.
Obviously my app, and my platform are both fine, because everything works over HTTP. But I'm not sure if this is a plugin issue, an SSL configuration problem etc.

I haven't been able to find anything useful on the internet. Based on some SO threads and other forums, some users suggested that if you **don't** encode the server URI, it should work fine. It didn't.

Others suggested that if you set the **chunkedMode** property to **false** it should solve the issue. Again, it didn't. I'm not even sure what's going wrong here. But I'm guessing it's something to do with my SSL Cert. on the production server.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify any confusions, the FileTransfer plugin seems to be working fine.
I think we can safely ignore those warnings in Xcode (boring_SSL).
However, I'd still like to know what they're about and how we can fix them properly.